# An error occurred while installing the npm driver using brew

Tags: npm, bigchaindb

I'm trying to execute the command of

> npm install bigchaindb-driver

using npm, but I keep getting errors.

I installed npm using

> brew

, and when I looked for the solution, I deleted all npm and node and installed it again.

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/ed25519/src/ed25519.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.13.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/junghyun2ing/node_modules/ed25519
gyp ERR! node -v v14.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN name@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN name@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ed25519@0.0.4 (node_modules/ed25519):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ed25519@0.0.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ bigchaindb-driver@4.1.2
updated 1 package and audited 515 packages in 18.799s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 7 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: thx reply! I installed that you said, but an error was added.